# Pytorch detach() function failed to be excuated on different GPU severs

Tags: gpu, pytorch

Recently, our lab bought a new server with 9 GPUs and I want to run my programming on this machine. However, I do not change my right code and I got an unexpected error like the following.

```
THCudaCheck FAIL file=/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1535491974311/work/aten/src/THC/THCGeneral.cpp line=663 error=11 : invalid argument
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 166, in <module>
    p_img.copy_(netG(p_z).detach())
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 477, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/szhangcj/python/GBGAN/celebA_attention/sagan_models.py", line 100, in forward
    out,p1 = self.attn1(out)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 477, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/szhangcj/python/GBGAN/celebA_attention/sagan_models.py", line 32, in forward
    energy =  torch.bmm(proj_query,proj_key) # transpose check
RuntimeError: cublas runtime error : the GPU program failed to execute at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1535491974311/work/aten/src/THC/THCBlas.cu:411
```

However, I can run my programming successfully on the old machine with 4 GPUs. I am not sure what the problem is and it seems that the error is caused by the `detach()` function. My code is as the following.

```
z_b = torch.FloatTensor(opt.batch_size, opt.z_dim).to(device)
img_b = torch.FloatTensor(opt.batch_size, 3, 64, 64).to(device)
img_a = torch.FloatTensor(opt.batch_size, 3, 64, 64).to(device)
p_z = torch.FloatTensor(pool_size, opt.z_dim).to(device)
p_img = torch.FloatTensor(pool_size, 3, 64, 64).to(device)

## evaluation placeholder
show_z_b = torch.FloatTensor(100, opt.z_dim).to(device)
eval_z_b = torch.FloatTensor(250, opt.z_dim).to(device) # 250/batch * 120 --> 300000

optim_D = optim.Adam(netD.parameters(), lr=opt.lr_d) # other param?
optim_G = optim.Adam(netG.parameters(), lr=opt.lr_g) #?suitable
criterion_G = nn.MSELoss()

eta = 1
loss_GD = []
pre_loss = 0
cur_loss = 0
G_epoch = 1
for epoch in range(start_epoch, start_epoch + opt.num_epoch):
    print('Start epoch: %d' % epoch)
    ## input_pool: [pool_size, opt.z_dim] -> [pool_size, 32, 32]
    netD.train()
    netG.eval()
    p_z.normal_()
    # print(netG(p_z).detach().size())
    p_img.copy_(netG(p_z).detach())

    for t in range(opt.period): 

        for _ in range(opt.dsteps):

            t = time.time()
            ### Update D
            netD.zero_grad()
            ## real
            real_img, _ = next(iter(dataloader)) # [batch_size, 1, 32, 32]
            img_b.copy_(real_img.squeeze().to(device))
            real_D_err = torch.log(1 + torch.exp(-netD(img_b))).mean()
            print("D real loss", netD(img_b).mean())
            # real_D_err.backward()

            ## fake
            z_b_idx = random.sample(range(pool_size), opt.batch_size)
            img_a.copy_(p_img[z_b_idx])
            fake_D_err = torch.log(1 + torch.exp(netD(img_a))).mean() # torch scalar[]
            loss_gp = calc_gradient_penalty(netD, img_b, img_a)
            total_loss = real_D_err + fake_D_err + loss_gp
            print("D fake loss", netD(img_a).mean())
            total_loss.backward()

            optim_D.step()

        ## update input pool            
        p_img_t = p_img.clone().to(device)
        p_img_t.requires_grad_(True)
        if p_img_t.grad is not None:
            p_img_t.grad.zero_()
        fake_D_score = netD(p_img_t)

        fake_D_score.backward(torch.ones(len(p_img_t)).to(device))


        p_img = img_truncate(p_img + eta * p_img_t.grad)
        print("The mean of gradient", torch.mean(p_img_t.grad))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the version mismatching between the RTX GPU cards and the CUDA driver.